# How can I create model such that either it is empty string or Dict in pydantic

Tags: python, pydantic

I want to create pydantic model for following situation
Either result will be

```
{
    "dataStores": ""
}
```

or it will be

```
{
    "dataStores": {
        "dataStore": [
            {
                "name": "sf",
                "href": "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/sf/datastores/sf.json"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

my models looks like this as of now

```
class DataStoreInBulk(BaseModel):
    name: str = ...
    href: str = ...

class DataStoreDict(BaseModel):
    dataStore: List[DataStoreInBulk] 

class DataStoresModel(BaseModel):
    dataStores: DataStoreDict = ''
```

I think I need to make changes in `DataStoresModel` which either should have data following `DataStoreDict` or simply `''` no other string is accepted . I tried

```
class DataStoresModel(BaseModel):
    dataStores: Union[DataStoreDict, str] = ''
```

but then problem is that any string will become valid value

Comment: Have you tried using typing.Literal? https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal

Answer (score 0):

`Literal` worked for this case

```
from typing import Union,Literal
    
class CoveragesStoresModel(BaseModel):
        coverageStores: Union[CoveragesStoresDict,Literal['']] = ''
```